# base board transition piece

Tags: baseboard

We have already laid baseboard in both rooms but when we got to where they meet, two different levels. Is there a way to put maybe a sloping piece so they meet? What should I do? The flooring has about a half inch difference.   Also one side is at a corner and the other is just at a straight wall

Answer (score 1):

IMO, a sloping piece would look awful.

Better to find something that 'explains' the transition. Normally, this wouldn't be an issue if you have a doorway or archyway between the two rooms, so that you would have an architrave that would create a vertical division between the two rooms.

If the two rooms merge, the ideal would obviously been to have discovered the difference beforehand and to cut down the height of the baseboard in the room with the higher floor to end up with a consistent baseboard height. I am assuming that you don't wish to remove any and cut it down (or build up the lower baseboard, if that's possible, for example if it is not molded then you could add additional height without removing what's there).

If it is molded, then I would cut a section of the molding and create vertical 'ends' to both the high and low sections (for example with a mitered joint, like a picture frame), making sure that the vertical pieces join neatly to both ends of the existing horizontal runs, and also to each other, thus creating a division, but one that will hopefully look sensible.